# Quotient of a cylinder by the product of a rotation and translation

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Let $D$ be the unit disk, and 
$$f : D \times \mathbb R \rightarrow D \times \mathbb R$$
be defined by 
$$f(z,t)=(e^{2i\pi \alpha}z, t+1)$$
where $\alpha$ is an irrational number.
Now consider $X = (D \times \mathbb{R})/f$.

Since $f$ acts discretely, $X$ is $3$-manifold. Also it somehow fibers above the circle. Is there a description of $X$ ?

Comment: never mind, it's a full torus, isn't it ?

Comment: How are you think of a 'function' acting on a manifold? Doesn't the action have to be by a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a filled-in torus $D\times S^1$. The map 
$$\phi(z,t) = (e^{2\pi i \alpha t}z,t)$$ 
is a homeomorphism of $D\times \mathbb{R}$ onto itself, which conjugates $f$ to $g(z,t) = (z,t+1)$: 
$$
\phi^{-1}(f(\phi(z,t)) = (z,t+1)
$$
The quotient by $g$ is $D\times S^1$.